# RewriteCond checking file existence on parent directory

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, parent

I'm trying to redirect all requests to a script if the requested file or directory doesn't exist, but I need to improve this .htaccess in order to check if the file exists on the parent folder. 
I currently have:

```
RewriteEngine on

# check if requested file or directory exists
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# map requests to contentpage.php and appends it as a query string
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)$ contentpage.php?url=$2&lang=$1
```

now, this .htaccess successfully redirects 
*en/products.php* -> *contentpage.php?url=products.php&lang=en* **only** if *products.php* doesn't exists on the child directory /en/ (and actually the directory /en/ doesn't physically exists, so the RewriteCond fails to filter when I have a file *products.php* on the parent directory).
 
 I need to check if the file exists on the top directory where my files are. It needs to redirect only the language directories, like /en /es /de /pt .etc  
Anyone has an idea how to solve this? thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put your rules in a htaccess file in your top directory; this way, if you have

```
 /parentdir
     /en
     /es 
     /de
```

even if you access the parent path or the child paths:

- /parentdir/products.php
- /parentdir/en/products.php

the /parentdir/.htaccess rules are evaluated
So you can use a ruleset like this:

```
# check if requested file does not exists in the child dir
# check if requested file does not exists in the child dir
# if does not exists... check if it also does not exists in the parent dir
RewriteCond /parentdir/$1/$2 !-f
RewriteCond /parentdir/$2 !-f
RewriteRule ^/parentdir/(es|en|fr|de)/(.*)$ contentpage.php?url=$2&lang=$1

# check if requested file does not exists in the parent dir
RewriteCond /parentdir/$1 !-f
RewriteRule ^/parentdir/(.*)$ contentpage.php?url=$2&lang=$1
```